# My accounts in drop down

Tags: account, screen-flow

How do we enable my accounts to be a pick list in accounts in lighting?
I am assuming we need to add the option behind the scenes. Right now the account defaults on everyones to ALL ACCOUNTS.

Comment: Why is this tagged screen-flow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about the standard Account tab behavior in Lightning (not Classic),  then you have some options.

You can let users "pin" their own default view.
You can also let users customize their own navigation, including the dropdown > add to navigation on any standard list view's webtab in lightning.

As of writing (~Spring'23) it appears an admin cannot force a default List View for all users.  Instead the users must do it themselves. There is an idea around this here: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdccYUAR/set-default-list-view-for-all-users-as-an-administrator

Comment: Issue is that our users have only ALL ACCOUNTS, Recently viewed accounts, and two others to choose to pin. I am looking for a list of MY ACCOUNTS to add to the drop down list.